# Androidでこのレイアウトを実現したい

Tags: android

この問題には丸一日費やしても解決できませんでした。。。。
レイアウト関係に詳しい方お願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
背景の変な模様が↓xmlで言うなら背景として row_bg が設定されているルートのLLです。
（実際はルートではないですがこのサンプルxml内でのルート）

↑半透明のグレーが↓xmlで言うなら contentArea　のidのビュー
その中の白文字の「ああああ」が　message　のidのビュー

↑nameから始まっているのが↓でのnameのidがついているビュー
timeも同様です。

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/row_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoArea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentArea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/row_content_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

contentArea 内は今回説明に不要なので一つだけビューを残して省略しているので LinearLayout になっています。
TextView １つだけしか入っていないのと同じように考えてもらっても同じ動作になるので１つしかないと考えてもらっても結構です。

やりたいことは、単純に
contentArea の minWidth に infoArea の width を指定して、
infoArea の minWidth に contentArea の width を指定した感じのレイアウトにしたいです。
contentArea　と　contentArea　はまず、お互い　wrap_content　でサイズを決定後、横幅を横幅の大きい方に合わせるという感じになります。
なので上記のように minWidth でお互いの wrap_content の横幅を指定できればベストです。

ただ、このコードのままでは実現できていませんが、 time は親ビューの右端にくっつけたいです。
name に width=0dp & weight=1 を指定した感じです。
name が 親の余った横幅を埋めるので time は自然と親ビューの右にくっつきます。

ビューの背景の関係でどうしてもこのようにしなければなりません。
このxmlでのルートビューは実際はルートではなく、親のコンテンツエリアが許す限りコンテンツに合わせて横幅が可変していきます。

### 説明その２（↑でやりたいことが理解できた方は読まなくても大丈夫です）

このxmlでのルートビューは　吹き出し全体　になります。
drawable/row_bg　は吹き出しの形をしていると考えてもらえるといいかと思います。

そして、吹き出しの中は２行で構成されています。
１行めは　名前、時間
２行めは　メッセージ本文です。

メッセージ本文にも背景指定があります。

時間は吹き出しの右にくっつけます
時間の親ビューの横幅が時間の親の親の横幅を埋め尽くすとして、時間は親ビューの右端にくっつける感じです。
（説明下手で難しく感じるかもしれないですが、要するにただ単に吹き出し全体のできるだけ右に位置します）

１行めと２行めはそれぞれコンテンツサイズを計算し、
計算後、お互いの行とくらべて横幅が小さい方は大きい方にサイズを変更します。
そうすることで、
・１行めは最低でも自分のコンテンツ領域を確保しつつ、２行めより小さかったら２行めの横幅になり、時間を右にくっつくける事ができる
・メッセージは最低でも自分のコンテンツ幅を確保しつつ、１行めより小さかったら１行めの横幅になり、メッセージの背景が横いっぱいに表示される。
ただ、メッセージの自分のコンテンツ幅を確保とは親が許す限りいくらでも横に大きく可変できる。
なので、メッセージの横幅が無限大だとしたらこのxmlでのルートビューの親ビューのコンテンツエリアサイズになるということです。
（難しいことではなく、普通にアンドロイドのレイアウト機能に備わっている機能です
テキストビューにwrap_contentを指定した場合、親が許す限りの横幅で、限界まで来たら勝手に改行されるという普通の機能）

### ここから下は私の失敗Reportなので読まなくても大丈夫です。

試したのは LinearLayout, TableLayout, GridLayout です。
これらの中で一番目的の見た目（minWidthを設定したような動作）になったのは、 GridLayout ですが、おそらく一番今回使用 で・き・な・い レイアウトになります。
なぜなら、セル単位での背景指定がないため、セルのを伸ばした時、伸ばされた部分がセルの背景ではなく GridLayout 全体で指定する背景になってしまうからです。
レイアウトの記述が変わり、背景リソースの設定箇所も変わるので説明しにくいのですが、不可能だと思われます。
できるとすれば、 cell の要素を最初は wrap_content にして、すべての cell サイズが確定後、 cell のコンテンツを match_parent にして cell いっぱいに引き延ばすことですが、できるか分かりません。

GridLayout はこれもレイアウトの記述が変わり説明しにくいのですが、
下の行である message は上の行である infoArea の横幅に従って横幅を決めるため、messageの横幅の最大値がinfoAreaの横幅になってしまうので無理でした。
（このxmlでのルートビューの親ビューが許す限り可変にしたいので）

あと OnGlobalLayoutListener 内部でそれぞれに minWidth を設定する方法も試しましたがそもそもここでレイアウトサイズを変更すべきではないでしょうし、呼ばれるタイミングが描画後なのと問題がたくさんあってだめでした。

Comment: 文章だけでの説明ではわかりにくいように思いますので、デザイン案等の画像を貼ってみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 了解です画像追加しておきました

Comment: `contentArea`と`infoArea`のうちより幅が大きいものを両者の`width`にしたいという趣旨でよいでしょうか？一つ一つの`cell`の大きさが全て親と同じ幅で良いのであれば簡単ですが、それぞれ別にしたいのであれば難しいと思いますね（`time`を右寄せする条件があるので）。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ふむふむ。。パズルのようでなかなか面白い問題ですね。

XMLだけで実現するのは無理そうなのでカスタムViewを作ってみました。

```
public class MaxLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    // コンストラクタ...（省略）

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // 全ての子要素の幅を計算
        int maxWidth = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            );
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, child.getMeasuredWidth());
        }

        // 最大値をこのビューの幅として設定する
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth, MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec));
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

XML内では以下のように使用してください。
（com.exampleの部分はパッケージ名に置き換えてください）

```
<com.example.MaxLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.example.MaxLinearLayout>
```

レイアウトエディタのプレビューで確認した限りではこれで要件を満たしているように思いますがいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます；；
もう諦めかけていました！
感謝感激です！